# Java MVC Framework: Am i allowed to handle exceptions in the Controller(C)?

Tags: java, exception, model-view-controller

Our lecturer gave us a sample model portion of a simple java software to practice on. I have created the controller and view sections of the software myself.

Most of the exceptions which are related to the software are handled by the model itself. However, I have handled smaller exceptions(invalid user input,mainly number format exceptions) in the the action listeners in my controller itself, as it is easier to throw back input errors via the view directly.

Is this the best practice/allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a matter of best practice or being allowed, you handle errors where it makes sense to do so.

Normally a Controller will adapt the user input data to the type of data expected by the Model. If that data has validation errors it makes sense to handle it first hand in the controller and not propagate it to the Model where it will be rejected.

In the Controller you handle all cases that can't generate a proper call to the Model: invalid parameters, required parameters missing etc, and you also catch the exceptions thrown by the Model (which are business exceptions) and send them to appropriate views for display.